# 32-bits as hex number in C with simple function call

Tags: c, function, hex, printf, 32-bit

I would like to know if I could get away with using printf to print 32 bits of incoming binary data from a microcontroller as a hexadecimal number. I already have collected the bits into an large integer variable and I'm trying "%x" option in printf but all I seem to get are 8-bit values, although I can't tell if that's a limitation with printf or my microcontroller is actually returning that value.

Here's my code to receive data from the microcontroller:

```
 printf("Receiving...\n");
 unsigned int n=0,b=0;
 unsigned long lnum=0;
 b=iolpt(1); //call to tell micro we want to read 32 bits
 for (n=0;n<32;n++){
     b=iolpt(1); //read bit one at a time
     printf("Bit %d of 32 = %d\n",n,b);
     lnum<<1; //shift bits in our big number left by 1 position
     lnum+=b; //and add new value
 }
 printf("\n Data returned: %x\n",lnum); //always returns 8-bits
```

The iolpt() function always returns the bit read from the microcontroller and the value returned is a 0 or 1.

Is my idea of using %x acceptable for a 32-bit hexadecimal number or should I attempt something like "%lx" instead of "%x" to try to represent long hex even though its documented nowhere or is printf the wrong function for 32-bit hex? If its the wrong function then is there a function I can use that works, or am I forced to break up my long number into four 8-bit numbers first?

Comment: Since `lnum` is a `long`, then yes you should really use `l` prefix as in `"%lx"`. And it's *well* documented by just about any book, tutorial or [`printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: Also, you might get all 32 bits, but maybe the upper 24 are just zero? Though your use of the wrong `printf` format can lead to false results (and [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), really) if `sizeof(int) < sizeof(long)`.

Comment: `printf("%08lx\n", lnum)` will print an `unsigned long int` in hexadecimal format, and will pad the number with zeros on the left so that you always see an 8-digit hex number.

Comment: `lnum<<1;` does not have any effect. It shifts `lnum` left one bit but does not put the result anywhere. You may want `lnum <<= 1;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("Receiving...\n");

iolpt(1); // Tell micro we want to read 32 bits.
    /*  Is this correct?  It looks pretty simple to be
        initiating a read.  It is the same as the calls
        below, iolpt(1), so what makes it different?
        Just because it is first?
    */

unsigned long lnum = 0;
for (unsigned n = 0; n < 32; n++)
{
    unsigned b = iolpt(1); // Read bits one at a time.
    printf("Bit %u of 32 = %u.\n", n, b);
    lnum <<= 1; // Shift bits in our big number left by 1 position.
        // Note this was changed to "lnum <<= 1" from "lnum << 1".
    lnum += b; // And add new value.
}

printf("\n Data returned: %08lx\n", lnum);
    /*  Use:
            0 to request leading zeros (instead of the default spaces).
            8 to request a field width of 8.
            l to specify long.
            x to specify unsigned and hexadecimal.
    */
```

Fixed:

- `lnum<<1;` to `lnum <<= 1;`.
- `%x` in final `printf` to `%08lx`.
- `%d` in `printf` in loop to `%u`, in two places.

Also, cleaned up:

- Removed `b=` in initial `b=iolpt(1);` since it is unused.
- Moved definition of `b` inside loop to limit its scope.
- Moved definition of `n` into `for` to limit its scope.
- Used proper capitalization and punctuation in comments to improve clarity and aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like that work for you?

```
printf("Receiving...\n");
 unsigned int n=0,b=0;
 unsigned long lnum=0;
 b=iolpt(1); //call to tell micro we want to read 32 bits
 for (n=0;n<32;n++){
     b=iolpt(1); //read bit one at a time
     printf("Bit %d of 32 = %d\n",n,b);
     lnum<<1; //shift bits in our big number left by 1 position
     lnum+=b; //and add new value
 }
 printf("\n Data returned: %#010lx\n",lnum); //now returns 32-bit
```

Comment: This still has the `lnum<<1` bug. It counts the bits instead of interpreting them as a binary numeral.